# SQL count distinct not count

Tags: sql, string, count, distinct

I have this "select" query below and when I try to count the "job title" it givs me only count of 1..
Seems it not count it at all.
I didn't find any workaround for it...

```
use [AdventureWorks2019]
select p.FirstName, p.LastName, e.JobTitle, e.HireDate, 
    count (distinct e.JobTitle) 'CountOftitle'
from HumanResources.Employee e
    left join person.Person p                 
    on e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
group by p.firstname, p.LastName, e.JobTitle, e.HireDate
```

The results and the issue

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbpzb.png)

Thanks

Comment: so are there supposed to be multiple records for p.firstname, p.LastName, e.JobTitle, e.HireDate that are the same?  You need to edit the question and show the sample data, and expected output

Comment: You have `... count (distinct e.JobTitle)` and then `group by ... e.JobTitle ...`. Do you see the problem?  If not, you need to study the basics of SQL aggregation.

Comment: as you group by jobtitle evry jobtitle has its own row, so the count will be every time 1, but i would expect for some users additional rows,with different jobtiles, but there are noe, so are you sure that there are counts bigger than 1 at all

Comment: With respect, it's impossible to tell the result you want from your question. The AdventureWorks sample data has diffferent names for each person ([see this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=8e7ef715674edcb0b208589f80665c63)] so there's no way you'll get a count > 1 when you group by firstname and lastname. There are job titles with multiple persons doing them.